# get protocol and www of url java

Tags: java, url, protocols, prefix

I'm loading a page in webview(android) and i need a full url of a page like "https://www.google.com", but i only have a string "google.com".

Some web site have http protocol, some others - https, some sites have www in it's name, the others don't.

If i do just `webView.loadUrl("google.com");` it doesn't work but if i add "http://www." then it works.

So i need to retrieve this prefix somehow for any web page. If you want to know, i get this url from chrome using accessibility service, the visible to user part of url in chrome on android starts with domain so it's the only thing i can get using accessibility service